# Определенный текст bold в <input> тэге

Tags: html, css

.< input type="text" style="width: 100%;" disabled class="form-control" value="Описание сервиса: Сервис для чего-то />

Мне нужно в Описание сервиса сделать в шрифте bold, остальное оставить таким.
Есть еще другие инпуты, так же нужно bold-ом отрисовать определенные места

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Это невозможно. Input - просто текстовое поле и в нем нельзя задавать какие-то характеристики лишь определенным элементам. Свойства применяются на все поле.

Могу только предложить сделать два input поля, склеить их, чтобы выглядело будто один и задать каждому полю нужный стиль.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно на инпут сверху наложить блок с текстом "Описание сервиса", если этот текст не нужно будет менять.

```
.input-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
input {
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 100px;
}
span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    font-weight: bold;
}


<div class="input-wrapper">
    <span>Описание сервиса:</span>
    <input type="text" value=" Сервис для чего-то" />
</div>
```